# azure data factory BlobEventsTrigger : set "advanced filter" programatically

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-data-factory, azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I am trying to set "advanced filter" of BlobEventsTrigger programmatically.

They are reset at each deployment. I need only 3 and having 7 of them are causing the job to start twice. It is super annoying to delete them manually after each deployment.

I have tried to add a field "advancedFilters" or "blobType" to the trigger json file without success.

```
"typeProperties": {
            "blobPathBeginsWith": "/bingofile/blobs/",
            "blobPathEndsWith": "/_SUCCESS",
            "ignoreEmptyBlobs": false,
            "scope": "/subscriptions/bingofilesup/resourceGroups/bingofilesup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/bingofilesup",
            "events": [
                "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated"
            ]
```

[image]

I've also tried `az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription update` but this library does not work when it comes to updating advanced filter. It asks an endpoint (which is normally a facultative argument) , and when provided the existing data factory endpoint, it fails reaching it.

I have checked the documentation about this endpoint and it is said to be the webhook endpoint .

> Endpoint where EventGrid should deliver events matching this event
> subscription. For webhook endpoint type, this should be the
> corresponding webhook URL. For other endpoint types, this should be
> the Azure resource identifier of the endpoint. It is expected that the
> destination endpoint to be already created and available for use
> before executing any Event Grid command.

[image: ![enter image description here]

But it does not work .

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
> 95e4fab5-163e-48ab-8cb2-b23432516e53. Webhook validation handshake
> failed for [webwook end point provided in the topic]. Http POST
> request failed with response code Unknown. For troublehooting, visit
> https://aka.ms/esvalidation.

Any observation or suggestion would be great, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, the endpoint `https://pmeastasia.svc.datafactory.azure.com:4443/triggerevent/BlobEventsTrigger/<>` is juts a base URL. When the events are sent to data factory or update subscription, azure will generate an endpoint with the base URL to do auth. So if you want to update the subscription with other tools, I think you need to use fildder to catch the request to get the whole endpoint at first.

[image]

Comment: you are right, or use the az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription show command with an optional argument [--include-full-endpoint-url {false, true}] ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67147720/what-endpoint-should-i-provide-when-updating-advanced-filters-with-az-eventgrid/67154125#67154125