# What endpoint should I provide when updating advanced filters with "az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription"?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cli, azure-eventgrid

I've tried to update advanced filter of a data factory blobevent trigger via `az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription update`.

It asks for an endpoint (actually this is facultative in the documentation), but if i don't put it i get :

> Invalid event subscription request: Supplied URL is invalid. It cannot
> be null or empty and should be a proper HTTPS URL like
> https://www.example.com.

This is my command:

```
az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription update 
--system-topic-name $systemtopicname 
--name $topicName 
-g $ResourceGroup 
--endpoint $endpoint 
--advanced-filter data.api StringIn CreateFile PutBlob CopyBlob
```

I have checked the documentation about this endpoint and it is said to be the webhook endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cli/azure/eventgrid/system-topic/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest)

> Endpoint where EventGrid should deliver events matching this event
> subscription. For webhook endpoint type, this should be the
> corresponding webhook URL. For other endpoint types, this should be
> the Azure resource identifier of the endpoint. It is expected that the
> destination endpoint to be already created and available for use
> before executing any Event Grid command.

[image: ![enter image description here]

But it does not work .

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID:
> 95e4fab5-163e-48ab-8cb2-b23432516e53. Webhook validation handshake
> failed for [webwook end point provided in the topic]. Http POST
> request failed with response code Unknown. For troublehooting, visit
> https://aka.ms/esvalidation.

I've also tried `az eventgrid event-subscription update` without more success!

Any observation or suggestion would be great, thanks in advance !

Comment: I found this command to the most useful to me when looking for the correct value for `az eventgrid event-subscription update --name` and `--system-resource-id`. Maybe it will work for you too: `az eventgrid event-subscription list --topic-type "Microsoft.Storage.StorageAccounts" --location <enterYourAzureLocation>`. All my EventGrids subscribe to Storage Accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the az command for updating an event subscription requires a full endpoint url included its query parameters.

Use the  [az eventgrid system-topic event-subscription show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/eventgrid/system-topic/event-subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az_eventgrid_system_topic_event_subscription_show) command with an optional argument *[--include-full-endpoint-url {false, true}]* to obtain the full endpoint url for your *$endpoint* variable.

Note, that the REST APIs for updating (PATCH) an event subscription can be done only for advanced filtering properties.